# Insert current timestamp into postgresql using VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, postgresql-9.3

This is my insert function into a postgresql database:

```
Private Sub insertIntoDataBase(date As DateTime, value As String)

    Dim Command As NpgsqlCommand

    Command = New NpgsqlCommand("insert into test_base(date,value) values(" + date + "," + value ")", conn)
    Dim rowsaffected As Int32
    Try
        rowsaffected = Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Console.WriteLine("It was added {0} lines in table table1", rowsaffected)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

What i want to do is to insert the current timestamp (in date field), without passing the value in the insert function. Like the field ID, which is inserted automaticly "autoincrement". Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know postgressql (in mySql it's possible) but in vb.net, maybe, you can change your code this way:

```
Private Sub insertIntoDataBase(value As String)

Dim Command As NpgsqlCommand
Dim mTS as datetime = DateTime.Now

Command = New NpgsqlCommand("insert into test_base(date,value) values(" + mTS.tostring("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm") + "," + value + ")", conn)
Dim rowsaffected As Int32
Try
    rowsaffected = Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Console.WriteLine("It was added {0} lines in table table1", rowsaffected)
Catch ex As Exception
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
End Try

End Sub
```

I used the format of timestamp for mySql: change it as you need.

Pay attention: in your code it was missing a "+"